# Unable to process Large numbers

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-function, exponentiation

A small spherical cell of diameter $1.616E^{-35}$ is exponentially multiplying as $2^n$ where n is the generation number. The duration of 1 generation is  $5.39E^{-44}$ second. And the cells cluster closely to form a big sphere. 
(a) How many cells exist after 13.79 billion years and what diameter sphere will they form?
(b) If radius is increasing at speed of light how fast is the surface area and volume of big sphere increasing?

Comment: The title should be improved to convey the subject of your question.  It appears that you have copied a multi-part exercise verbatim.  Please add your own thoughts about this problem, and distinguish where your efforts ran into a real difficulty.

Comment: Depends on what a billion is ... Also, how speed of light is expressed in the (not mentioned) units of length

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Heh.  Let's assume the American billion, for the sake of discussion.  After all, lifetime of universe is about that.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, but the cell diameter suspiciously look like Planck length - but expressed in meters, not American furlongs ... ;)

Comment: I was trying to find out if Space could be made up of Planck dimension cells of primordial energy continuously reproducing. And if so, what size would they have reached by now (96 billion light years diameter of a flattened sphere of cells?). If the number is growing very rapidly then is it possible that 'death' of cells occur at boundaries of the Universe and at breakdowns in between (Black Holes).

Comment: What does it mean for a spherical cell to be exponentially multiplying?

Comment: @hardmath: Offtopic, but I couldn't help it: the age of the universe is not "about" 1 American billion years, but rather 12-13 billion. After all, our young Solar system is only about 4 billion years old.

Comment: @AlexM: My reference was to the figure $13.79$ billion years used in the problem part (a).  British billion is a thousand times the American billion.

Answer (score 2):

(a) The age of the universe is about $4.3\cdot 10^{17}$ seconds, which is about $8\cdot 10^{60}$ Planck times (aka. generations). Raising $2$ to the power of this large number results in a number with $\approx 8\cdot 10^{60}\cdot\log_{10}2\approx 2.4\cdot 10^{60} $ **digits**. The radius (or diameter or any reasonable multiple of either) of a sphere is approximately the cube root of this number times the Planck langth, so a $\approx .8\cdot 10^{60}$ digit number times  $\approx 10^{-35}$ meters - but that factor merely scratches off 35 digits from our number, hence the radius *still* has $\approx .8\cdot 10^{60}$ digits when expressed in meters (or any other comprehensible unit anywhere from Planck length via meter and furlong and parsec to diameter-of-the-visible-universe).

(b) This part deals with much smaller growth. Just plug $r=ct$ into the surface and volume formula to see that the surface grows quadratic ovre time and volume grows cubic over time.

Comment: Thank you so much Hagen von Eitzen. You have answered me. Tell me, is there any tool I can use to do further analysis. For instance, I want to know when my sphere will reach 1 m diameter. What will happen when the Universe is 10 seconds old, etc.

Comment: 1 m (or even the size of the observable Universe) is reached "almost instantly". Even after a femtosecond, or $10^{29}$ Planck times, we have ten to the a lot *digits* in the number of cells, hence once again a mind-bogglingly large sphere.